# Jquery function doesn't work on DOM elements added by AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom

here is my code:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "a.php",
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        data: data,
        complete: function (xhr, result) {
            if (result == "success") {
                $("#field-option").remove();
                var chaine = '<section id="field-put"><ul>';
                var container;
                var passwords = xhr.responseText.split(";");
                for(var i= 0; i < passwords.length; i++) {
                    chaine += '<li><input type="text" class="put" id="field'+i+'" value="'+passwords[i]+'"><input type="button" value="Copy" name="copy" class="btn-put" data-clipboard-target="#field'+i+'"><span class="clear"></span></li>';

                }
                chaine += '</ul></section>';

                $("#main-area").append(chaine);

                $('#field0').shuffleText("My output text");

                new Clipboard('.btn-put');
            }
        }
    });
```

The problem is on the line

```
$('#field0').shuffleText("My output text");
```

The function shuffleText doesn't apply, because #field0 is generated by Ajax so append to the DOM after the initial DOM.

If #field0 is already in the initial DOM, shuffleText is applicate, but I need to applicate the function on the Ajax returns input elements...

How can #field0 be find after it is append to the DOM ?

Thanks for help

Comment: when does the event gets fired on field0?

Comment: try this $(document).on('click,'#field0',function(){  $(this).shuffleText("My output text") });

Comment: I don't want to call the function on the click event...

Comment: when does this function gets triggered on the field? OnLoad?

Comment: You are calling it after the element gets inserted so there is no reason it shouldn't work as shown. It sounds like you are repeating `ID's in the page and ID's must be unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shuffleText` dont work on text input fields.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/7Lv0rq5r/1/) of your example not working.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/7Lv0rq5r/) of your example working by replacing the `input` with a `div`.

```
for(var i= 0; i < passwords.length; i++) {
     chaine += '<li><div class="put" id="field'+i+'">'+passwords[i]+'"</div><input type="button" value="Copy" name="copy" class="btn-put" data-clipboard-target="#field'+i+'"><span class="clear"></span></li>';
}
```